# Association in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question with Rails 3.1 associations. When you have a one-to-many association you put the `has_many` operators on the many side of the relationship and the usual example does something like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :orders
end
```

My question is how should I do this if the class name is `Orders`? Should I put `has_many :orders` or should I always name my models using singular nouns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rails convention](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-model) states that model names should always be singular, so you should never have a model class named `Orders`; it would probably just be `Order`.

Comment: and what if i had a model with WorkArea as name?? should i use :work_areas or :workareas

Comment: `:work_areas` is the proper way to snake-case a camel-cased name.

Comment: @RenéAlfredoGarcía If my answer answered your question, be sure to [click the check mark to the left of it to accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) :)